# `UIColor` initializer not visible for watchOS framework

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, watchos

Xcode reports a compile error when trying to instantiate a UIColor using `init?(named name: String, in bundle: Bundle?, compatibleWith traitCollection: UITraitCollection?)` on a watchOS framework.

Steps:

1. Create a sample iOS app
2. Add a new iOS framework to the xcodeproj. This will generate a new xcodeproj that will be added to the main one.
3. Add a new watchOS target to the framework's xcodeproj
4. Create a .swift file where you declare a UIColor instantiated using `init?(named name: String, in bundle: Bundle?, compatibleWith traitCollection: UITraitCollection?)` and set the target membership to both the iOS and watchOS frameworks.

```
let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.alexdmotoc.MyKit")
let myColor1 = UIColor(named: "MyColor1", in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)!
```

5. Select the watchOS framework's scheme and try to build.

Xcode reports a compile error: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"; project doesn't build.

Am I doing something wrong?

Attached some images for reference.

[image: the crash I get when trying to instantiate the colors from the assets folder]
[image: the assets folder with the colors]

Comment: "Add a new iOS framework to the xcodeproj. This will generate a new xcodeproj that will be added to the main one." No, it doesn't. It sounds to me like you're adding the framework incorrectly.

Comment: I'm guessing this has something to do with [`UITraitCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection) not existing in watchOS? What's weird is that the method shows up when you go to the [generated interface of UIColor.h](https://i.imgur.com/VQp7yAk.png) for a watchOS target, and even [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/2877381-init) say the method is available for watchOS.

Comment: @matt, Yes, it does. I want the framework to be added to the main xcodeproj. As you can see in the screenshots, the Navigator's hierarchy contains the main xcodeproj and the framework xcodeproj. When you create the framework via `cmd+shift+n` you are able to select to which project it should be added (if any). iOS framework builds successfully, watchOS not. Please read the entire post carefully.

Comment: "When you create the framework via cmd+shift+n" OK, that's good info. That's not how I would add a framework to a project.

Comment: I don't know fully, but I think UIKit isn't available in watchOS. Suppose you conditionally import UIKit with `#if os(iOS)`?

That said, I'm running into the same issue in a watch-only framework. UITraitCollection doesn't exist in watchOS, yet the `init(named:in:compatibleWith:)` initializer allegedly is available since watchOS 4. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @UberJason I didn't pursue it further. Added a bug here: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-12757

Comment: Same question with some follow up answers - I was able to bridge access using a SwiftUI Color object on watchOS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63885449/how-to-access-color-from-an-asset-catalog-in-a-shared-framework-in-a-watchos-app/67163216#67163216

Comment: In the docs it clearly states that init(name:in:compatibilityWith:) is not available in watchOS. @crafterm's response is the best option we have right now. Create a SwiftUI Color and initialize a UIColor with it. And file Feedback to Apple, of course.